# Best way to preview private S3 documents

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Users can upload documents through the my site. It it stored in a private AWS S3 bucket. If they want to preview those uploaded files from my site, I generate a pre-signed URL and stick it in an `<embed>` tag. I was wondering if this is the best way to do this?

It currently works most of the time, however a few users don't get the preview, instead their browser wants to download the file. Mostly on Windows machines.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the content type for the files that try to download? You can see it in the metadata for the object in S3

Comment: Yeah your right, s3 auto sets it to ocset-stream, no good. Will have to set the content-type before I upload it. Thanks man.